# Count the latest same values from column python

Tags: python, pandas

i have data like this:

```
   id   a   b   c   d
    1   y   y   z   z
    2   y   z   y   y
    3   y   y   y   y
```

i want to count value `"y"` from column `a b c d` from the last it change like this:

```
id    count_y
1     2
2     1
3     4
```

could you please help me with this?

Comment: For you second row in your desired output, do you mean to have `count_y` be 3?

Comment: @Jeff no it should be 1 because i dont want to count it after change the value to x

Comment: so it's "latest" from right to left, I guess? from `d` to `a`?

Comment: i want to count the latest it change from `a` to `b`. like id `2` it change in column `b` so i count it as `1`. @Adam.Er8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do `cumprod` after `set_index`

```
s = df.set_index('id').eq('y').cumprod(axis = 1).sum(axis = 1)
s = s.reset_index(name='count_y')
s
Out[33]: 
   id  count_y
0   1        2
1   2        1
2   3        4
```

Answer (score 2):

As explanation in your comment, I think you may try this

```
df.set_index('id').eq('y').cummin(1).sum(1)

Out[11]:
id
1    2
2    1
3    4
dtype: int64
```